# jquery: Iterate over json result

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have json result as follow:

```
{"Result":"OK","Records":[{"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26518},
{"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26519}]}
```

How do I iterate over Records? I want `impTxnId` and `forecastedId` values.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '<%=getMatchedTransactionsURL%>',
        type : "post",
    });
    request.done(function (data) {
        alert(data); // This displays the data. 
        $.each(data.Records, function(i, record) {
            alert(record.impTxnId + " " + record.forecastedId);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have jQuery tag:

```
$.each(data.Records, function(i, record) {
    alert(record.impTxnId + " " + record.forecastedId);
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: e is undefined` :(

Comment: Found out the mistake. Missing ` dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var records = json_result.Records;
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    /* do stuff with records[i].impTxnId and records[i].forcastedId */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"Result":"OK",Records:[{"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26518},
    {"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26519}]}

for(var i = 0; i < json.Records.length;i++){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var j='{"Result":"OK","Records":[{"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26518},'+
      '{"impTxnId":12231,"forecastedId":26519}]}';


var a=JSON.parse(j);
   $.each(a.Records, function(i, record) {
   alert(record.impTxnId + " " + record.forecastedId);
});
```